# issue in consuming wcf service in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a class and interface like this in my wcf application IService1.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string insertValues(empInfo objInfo);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class empInfo
    {
        string _organizationName = string.Empty;
        string _organizationAddr = string.Empty;
        int? _totalemp;
    }
```

And in Service1.svc.cs, i have implemented that interface.

```
 public class Service1 : IService1
 {

 public string insertValues(empInfo objInfo)
        {
            .....
        }
 }
```

then i have created a empty mvc4 client application to consume this wcf service.
i have added the ServiceReference,Now its appear in the service reference folder as ServiceReference1.Then i did this
1. created a controller named Defalut1controller.
2. In this controller i try to add the following line
 `ServiceReference1.Service1Client proxy = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();`
inside the ActionResult. But unable to get the ServiceReference1 word.

its (ServiceReference1) appearing when i update my service like this

From - `string insertValues(empInfo objInfo);` - To -  `string insertValues(string objInfo);`

and now i have build this wcf application, and update the service reference  in my client mvc4 application. Now the

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client proxy = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
```

line is enabled.

I have tried with the .net web application to consume the same, i can able to do without any problem, what i have missed with mvc4, please help. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer, thanks to stackoverflow.

This is the solution:

1. Right click on Service Reference
2. Select Configure Service Reference
3. Select Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies
4. Just select everything except "Newtonsoft.json"

It worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

The question itself and the problem you are facing is a bit unclear for me but have you actually tried exposing any public properties on your `empInfo` data contract? Cause right now you have only 3 private fields which will not be generated in the proxy code on the client side.

Comment: Yes I'm having public properties like
 public string OrganizationName
        {
            get { return _organizationName; }
            set { _organizationName = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string OrganizationAddr
        {
            get { return _organizationAddr; }
            set { _organizationAddr = value; }
        }
[DataMember]
        public int? TotalEmployees
        {
            get { return _totalemp; }
            set { _totalemp = value; }
        }

Comment: I got the answer, thanks to stackoverflow.

This is the solution:
1) Right click on Service Reference
2) Select Configure Service Reference
3) Select Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies
4) Just select everything except "Newtonsoft.json"
It worked for me as well.

@dmusial Thanks for you response.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has fixed this issue in this update: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2750149